# Get data and read short string from txt-file in SPSS syntax

Tags: syntax, spss

I would like to use GET DATA to open my data. Then read a string from a text file. The string would be a date (eg. "2017-09-02 13:24") which I would use in filtering the data set before saving as .sav.

Is this possible? Or any other suggestion on how to import external information to use while processing the data set?

With `ADD FilE` I know its possible to open up two different data sets. However, I have to use `GET DATA`.

The .sps-file is run from spss job-file.

Comment: open your text file with `get data`,  use `dataset name mytextfile.` (or some other name of course), now open your other file with the date and name it too (`dataset name mydatesfile.`). Now you can use `match files` to get the date into a new column in the data, and use it to filter or select cases.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this and it works.